# Stopping condition for simple DFS traversing

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

I'm trying to solve this [problem on topcoder](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=8268&rd=10794) as a practice , I tried implementing DFS solution for it , it works well except for a bug : it keeps traversing every unvisited cell even if it reached a dead end , the initial code was :

```
public void func(int[][] x, StringBuilder s, int i, int j, int n) {
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > n || j > n || x[i][j] == 1) {
        return;
    }
    s.append((char) (97 + j));
    s.append(n - i + 1 + "-");
    x[i][j] = 1;
    func(x, s, i, j + 1, n);
    func(x, s, i - 1, j, n);
    func(x, s, i + 1, j, n);
    func(x, s, i, j - 1, n);
    return;
}

public String dukePath(int n, String initPosition) {
    String p = initPosition;
    int x[][] = new int[n][n];
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("");
    func(x, s, n - Integer.parseInt(p.charAt(1) + ""), (int) p.charAt(0) - 97, n - 1);
    s.replace(s.length() - 1, s.length(), "");
    if (s.length() > 40) {
        s.replace(20, s.length() - 20, "...");
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

so I tried to modify the signature of the function "func()" by adding a boolean flag , and initial position (z,y) to compare the current cell with ; if the code tries to revisit the initial position then it should return , but it also didn't work..

How could I stop traversing when reaching a dead-end or the initial position again ?

Comment: You're marking `x[i][j] = 1;` when you reach a dead end, but you're not marking it as not visited `x[i][j] = 0;` when you backtrack.

Comment: I just want it to stop when it reaches a dead end , not to explore another cells , so no there is no need for backtracking i guess

Comment: Try it without StringBuilder and pass regular Strings. You might need to return String as well.

Comment: @a.u.r What do you mean by "dead end"? Currently you are always checking all four adjacent positions...

Comment: @veredesmarald I meant to get to a position where all neighbouring cells are visited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are approaching this problem incorrectly, all you need to do is to move to the lexicographically greatest neighbour at every step until you reach a point where you have visited all neighbouring cells. This is simple iteration and doesn't require DFS:

```
public static String dukePath(int n, String initPosition) {
    int x = initPosition.charAt(0) - 'a';
    int y = n - (initPosition.charAt(1) - '0');
    boolean grid[][] = new boolean[n][n];
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(initPosition);

    while (true) {
        grid[x][y] = true;

        if (x < (n - 1) && !grid[x + 1][y])
            x++; // Right
        else if (y > 0 && !grid[x][y - 1])
            y--; // Up
        else if (y < (n - 1) && !grid[x][y + 1])
            y++; // Down
        else if (x > 0 && !grid[x - 1][y])
            x--; // Left
        else
            break; // Nowhere left to go!

        s.append("-" + (char)('a' + x) + (char)('0' + n - y));
    }

    if (s.length() > 40) {
        s.replace(20, s.length() - 20, "...");
    }

    return s.toString();
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println(dukePath(3, "b2"));
    System.out.println(dukePath(4, "d4"));
    System.out.println(dukePath(3, "a2"));
    System.out.println(dukePath(4, "d3"));
    System.out.println(dukePath(8, "a8"));
}
```

Gives the expected results:

```
b2-c2-c3-b3-a3-a2-a1-b1-c1
d4-d3-d2-d1-c1-c2-c3...b3-b2-b1-a1-a2-a3-a4
a2-b2-c2-c3-b3-a3
d3-d4-c4-c3-c2-d2-d1...b2-b3-b4-a4-a3-a2-a1
a8-b8-c8-d8-e8-f8-g8...a1-a2-a3-a4-a5-a6-a7
```

Comment: I knew the iterative solution before , but I tried to implement it using DFS.
As you can see my approach is pretty the same : favouring the right direction , then up , etc.. etc..
all I did was swapping the Xs and Ys.
Maybe I didn't clarify my problem:

for the third example , my code returns:

a2-b2-c2-c3-b3-a3-c1-b1-a1 instead of a2-b2-c2-c3-b3-a3 with excess cells "c1-b1-a1"

Comment: @a.u.r That is how DFS works. Once it hits a point where it can no longer continue it backtracks to a point where it can. DFS isn't designed to stop the first time it encounters a terminal node, you can modify it so that it does, but to what end? You are just adding a bunch of code that doesn't do anything.

Comment: @verdesmarald I believe you're right , now I got it.
another issue : if I had a target cell , then how could I terminate the code when I reach that cell ?

Comment: @a.u.r You could do something like modify your original `func` to return a `boolean`. At each cell you visit you return `true` if it matches the target criteria, and make sure you propagate the `true` back up the call stack, instead of continuing to the next neighbour. Note that if more than one path to the target exists, this will give  you the first path the DFS finds, not necessarily the best one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to create a set of objects containing i and j. In every call of func if this set contains the target object with i and j, it should not call the func function. This method both covers step backs and loops.

Comment: I tried this by adding the initial position as a parameter , and comparing the current cell to it ; to decide whether to stop or not , but it didn't work :

public void func(int[][] x , StringBuilder s,int i , int j , int n , boolean f , int z ,int y){
// z & y are the initial coordinates given in the problem
if(i==z && j==y && x[z][y]==1)
   f=true;
  if(f==true)
   return;
// rest of the code as the above

Comment: That does not work because your program can fall in a loop in the xy space that does not contain the original position. Generally, when you call those func function 4 times you need to check if the target position has not been seen before.

Comment: No, even when it gets to the initial position and changes boolean "f" to true it doesn't work

Comment: That's what I say, it does not work. because there are so many other loop paths that does not contain the initial position and they will run forever. If you want to run the problem only using one thread the solution of veredesmarald is simpler and does not have stack overflow problem. Otherwise if you insist on having a recursive solution you need this set of seen positions.